# Postgresql :how to refer to table which has multiple unique primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

trying to create the tables in postgresql, unable to create `ftotal` getting 
`ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "cur"`

```
CREATE TABLE con (
 con_code CHAR (3) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
 con_name VARCHAR (100)             NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE cur (
 cur_code   CHAR (3)        NOT NULL,
 cur_name   VARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
 con_code   CHAR (3)        NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE (cur_code,con_code),
 PRIMARY KEY (cur_code, con_code),
 FOREIGN KEY (con_code) REFERENCES con (con_code)
);

CREATE TABLE ftotal (
    eff_date    DATE        NOT NULL,
    con         CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    cur         CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eff_date,con,cur),
    FOREIGN KEY (con) REFERENCES con (con_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (cur) REFERENCES cur (cur_code)
);
```

Comment: In the `cur` table, `UNIQUE (cur_code,con_code)` is not needed since that's already the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key reference needs to be to the entire primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE ftotal (
    eff_date    DATE NOT NULL,
    con         CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    cur         CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eff_date, con, cur),
    FOREIGN KEY (con) REFERENCES con (con_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (cur, con) REFERENCES cur (cur_code, con_ode)
);
```